# R Shiny- Contingency Tables

Tags: shiny, contingency

I am unable to create Contingency table in Shiny. It results in both columns side by side rather than in cross tab.

```
output$currtarget<-renderTable({

    currtgt<- cstable %>%

      select(parent_id,tutor_id,status_name,first_name) #%>%

      xtabs(as.formula(paste0("~",status_name,"+",first_name),currtgt)

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me too, after updating all my packages today--it worked fine last week. Not sure why it changed, but it's *very* annoying!

Anyway, my workaround was to use `as.data.frame.matrix` and then set `include.rownames=TRUE` between the curly brace and last parenthesis.

```
renderTable = ({
...
my_tbl = addmargins(table(one_group, another_group))
printed_tbl = as.data.frame.matrix(my_tbl)
print_tbl
}, include.rownames=TRUE)
```